# Orfeo ERROR 4: Saving Images?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, ubuntu

I am using QGIS 2.18.4 Las Palmas under Ubuntu 16.04. Xenial. At startup, but particularly, when using Orfeo, I get error messages tagged as ERROR 4. My console output. At startup:

```
ERROR 4: /initrd.img: Keine Berechtigung. Most of all, Orfeo obviously can't save its outputs.
```

When using Orfeo (Supervised LibSVM classification):

```
ERROR 4: /tmp/processing0808ccc1678d4ad68ac22abbd3d1a967/4fa15f1ea4d2‌​4fb3b868f39e6e85e908‌​/out.tif: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden 

ERROR 4: /home/andreas/Schreibtisch/output.tif: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

I am fully aware that this may be trivial, however, I haven't been able to solve it anyway.

---

I could chown on this particular file. However 1. running sudo qgis returns: ERROR 4: `/initrd.img' not recognized as a supported file format. And even if changing the owner solved the problem, it wouldn't help me out regarding the outputs of the toolboxes. For instance, in my third error message, a new output.tif has to be created. For such situations, since files are new, chown woulnd't help. Am I right? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It says it doesn't have the necessary rights. Check the rights on initrd.img

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the owner is root. However, the problem is slightly more complicated, I am afraid. I could chown on this particular file. However 1. running sudo qgis returns: ERROR 4: `/initrd.img' not recognized as a supported file format. And even if changing the owner solved the problem, it wouldn't help me out regarding the outputs of the toolboxes. For instance, in my third error message, a new output.tif has to be created. For such situations, since files are new, chown woulnd't help. Am I right? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!